# gradle dependencies fails on multi-module project setup based on kotlin

Tags: gradle, kotlin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I have a multi-module gradle project setup based on gradle script kotlin. It seems I messed up the dependency management of the project but I'm unable to find the issue. Whenever I add a new dependency and run `gradle build` the build itself succeeds but it fails to add the dependency to the project. To analyse the issue I ran a `gradle dependencies` and there I can see that it fails to retrieve the dependencies as shown here:

```
> Task :dependencies

    ------------------------------------------------------------
    Root project
    ------------------------------------------------------------

    archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
    \--- project :nanoservices-web-api
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.2.21
     |    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.21
     |    |    \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.21
     |         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.21 (*)
     +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.21
     |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.21 (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web: FAILED
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator: FAILED
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa: FAILED
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache: FAILED
     +--- javax.cache:cache-api: FAILED
     +--- com.h2database:h2: FAILED
     \--- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin: FAILED

    default - Configuration for default artifacts.
    No dependencies
```

The gradle version I'm using is 5.4.1 Can anyone spot the error I made?
Below you can find the build files. This is the top level build.gradle.kts file:

```
allprojects {
    group = "localhost.playground"
    version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    base
}

dependencies {
// Make the root project archives configuration depend on every subproject
    subprojects.forEach {
        archives(it)
    }
}
```

The following is currently the only subproject.

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

buildscript {

    extra["kotlinVersion"] = "1.2.21"
    extra["springBootVersion"] = "1.5.10.RELEASE"

    val springBootVersion: String by extra
    val kotlinVersion: String by extra

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:$springBootVersion")
        classpath("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.1.0")
    }
}

val kotlinVersion: String by extra
val springBootVersion: String by extra

plugins {
    val kotlinVersion = "1.2.21"
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.spring") version kotlinVersion
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa") version kotlinVersion
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.0.4.RELEASE"
}

apply {
    plugin("org.springframework.boot")
    plugin("org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlinVersion")
    compile("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlinVersion")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")
    compile("javax.cache:cache-api")
    compile("com.h2database:h2")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")

    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test") {
        exclude(module = "junit")
    }
    testCompile("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.1.0")
    testRuntime("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.1.0")
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried adding version numbers explicitly to the dependencies? I know spring has their starter plugin that adds versions through BOM or something, but you may either not have that dependency or it may not be working

Comment: @AllanW This works as you would expect. I was just wondering since I closely followed an example where it seems one is not required to explicitly state the versions: https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-kotlin/blob/master/build.gradle.kts

Comment: As I understand the gradle-dependency-management plugin should handle the versions if I add the mavenBom as described [here](https://github.com/spring-gradle-plugins/dependency-management-plugin#importing-a-maven-bom). I added the lines to no avail though.

Comment: You don't have the milestone repo added so I'm not sure if that makes a difference. You can try removing the version names package by package to see what the culprit really is.

Comment: I found the problem. In the top level gradle build file I tried to add all subprojects dependencies to the archives configuration. Since the spring dependency management plugin is only enabled in the subproject it was not clear which version to add to the archives config. Hence the error. Removing the following lines solved the issue: 
    dependencies {
        subprojects.forEach {
            archives(it)
        }
    }

Thank you for your help.